# CKEditor - Apply Script

Tags: wysiwyg

I got a script that will change headlines etc in the CKEdtior. I'm sure a lot of you have done this before. Talking about the ckeditor.styles.js

Now, where do I apply this script into CKEditor? I can't find it anywhere. Can somone walk me through of how do add it into CKEditor

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to FTP into your site and go to `sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.styles.js`. There is not an admin option to do this, which it sounds like you expected.